# Why password validation fail using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to validate password using regex .my condition is that 
Password should have

1. One special character
2. One number
3. One lower case
4. One upper case
5. minimum 8 characters

Below is my code snippet

```js
var a = "Test@123"
if (/^(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.\d)(?=.[@$!%?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%?&]{8,}$/.test(a)) {
  console.log('=====true')
} else {
  console.log('false')
}
```

it should show `true` on console. but currently it is showing `false` why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed quantifiers in positive lookahead, currently

```
   (?=.[a-z])
```

Here `.` means match anything except new line since no quantifier so it will match only one time, `[a-z]` means match lowercase alphabet once, so your all positive lookaheads are looking for values at index `1` which can never satisfy all the positive lookaheads conditions as we are looking for different different values in each positive lookahead,

So when we use `(?=.*[a-z])` quantifier which means match anything zero or more time and then should be followed by lowercase alphabet, so it makes the values before condition dynamic

```js
var a = "Test@123"
if (/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%?&]{8,}$/.test(a)) {
  console.log('=====true')
} else {

  console.log('false')
}
```